# sed for finding and printing multiline blocks

Tags: sed

I have input which contains several simple multiline blocks.  All lines in the block match a certain pattern, only the last line matches a different pattern:

```
some junk
a1
some other junk

a2
a3
a4
B

some more junk
a5
```

I want to print all matching blocks (and suppress all other lines):

```
a2
a3
a4
B
```

My idea was to use the Hold Buffer of `sed` to achieve this:

```
sed -e '/a./H;/B/{H;x;p};d'
```

This works *almost* because it also prints the blocks which do not have the necessary end line:

```
a1
a2
a3
a4
B
```

My idea is to clean the hold buffer when neither pattern matches, but I found on way to achieve this.  Maybe my understanding of `sed` is too limited to see the obvious way to do it.

Comment: will the blocks be always separated by empty line? does this code `awk -v RS= '/^a.*B$/'` or this one `awk -v RS= '/^(a.\n)+B$/'` help? if not, please add more details

Comment: Both variants using `awk` don't work.  No, the blocks are not necessarily separated by newlines.

Comment: how about `perl -l -0777 -ne 'print /^(?:a.\n)+B$/mg'` then? note that the pattern is based on given sample, you'll have to change depending on your real use case

Comment: That works, yes.  But I would prefer to use `sed` for the task and manage to do it using the hold buffer, also because of course my real use case is a little more complex than the question I asked, and I have the feeling that it might be extremely simple to do that with `sed`.  I just need to find out how.  (I could have written a Python script to achieve this which would have looked very much like your Perl script.)

Comment: `sed -n '/a./!d;h;:1;n;//{H;b1;};/B/!d;H;x;p'` (you may need to do `/a./` instead of `//`)

Comment: @jhnc: Neither of those seems to work.

Comment: I suggest `sed -n '/^B$/{H;s/.//;x;p;};/^a.$/!{s/.*//;h;d;};H;'`

Comment: @Beta what version of sed? It works with gnu; busybox with the change; and bsd if you replace all the semicolons with newlines

Comment: @jhnc: I'm not sure; it's the one in OSX 18.2.0. If it they work in other versions, maybe I can reverse-engineer them to a variant that works with mine. But you seem to be using a branch; I prefer a more primitive solution to a branch, unless the branch makes things a lot more elegant.

Comment: branch *is* primitive - even Research-V7 has it. Try saving to a file, replacing the semicolons with newlines, and calling with `-f`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/a./!{:a;n;/\S/ba;b};h;:b;n;H;/a./bb;/\S/!b;/B/!ba;n;H;/\S/ba;x;p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by using the `-n` option.

If a group of lines does not begin with the required regexp, throw those lines away.

Otherwise, gather up those lines in the hold space until the regexp fails, then if the next line contains the second regexp and the line following that is empty, append those two lines to the hold space, swap to the hold space and print that group of lines. Repeat.

For all other cases do not print any lines.

N.B. This depends on the last line being empty.